# Backtracking algorithm to create all possible (distinct letters) words with fixed length?

Tags: php, python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I have all the possible BIG letters of the english alphabet "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYX" as charset.
I want to create all possible combination all "words" from this set, with fixed length 8 and distinct letters.

**Example of words:**

ABCDEFGH

PQELFKMB

XLOPQDEH

The algorithm that I've tried (found on stackoverflow, but don't have the link anymore) is this:

```
<?php
function getPermCount($letters, $count)
{
  $result = 1;
  // k characters from a set of n has n!/(n-k)! possible combinations
  for($i = strlen($letters) - $count + 1; $i <= strlen($letters); $i++) {
    $result *= $i;
  }
  return $result;
}

// Decodes $index to a $count-length string from $letters, no repeat chars.
function getPerm($letters, $count, $index)
{
  $result = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
    $pos = $index % strlen($letters);
    $result .= $letters[$pos];
    $index = ($index-$pos)/strlen($letters);
    $letters = substr($letters, 0, $pos) . substr($letters, $pos+1);
  }
  return $result;
}
$letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
echo '2 letters from 4:<br>';
for($i = 0; $i < getPermCount($letters, 3); $i++)
  echo getPerm($letters, 3, $i).'<br>';
?>
```

It works good, if I try with 3 letters, from what I've seen. But with length 8, I get 4.5 million possibilities. I've checked the result, but I don't see for example Q in the last 3 letters.

I've tried to find a random "word":
**MBFHPXSN**
And it's not found in the list. So ... there are not all possibilities.

**PS:** I get all the "words" with wget, so EVERYTHING that php gaves me should be in the file.

Do you guys have any other solution ?

The code is in php, but could be in almost anything, c#, python, java

Comment: here is a small script i wrote:
https://gist.github.com/lackovic10/1068c19b77fdd7900f95

Comment: thanks, but still I can't find MBFHPXSN for example ...

Answer (score 1):

4.5 million combinations doesn't nearly cut it. I guess PHP bails out before you've run out of memory.

There are `26*25*24*23*22*21*20*19` possible 8-letter words that you can construct from ASCII capital letters without duplicates. That's `62.990.928.000` words. Even if you could store them compactly, using only 8 bytes per word and no overhead, that means you'd need about `469 GB` of RAM. I doubt you have that much...

Comment: well, I run the php locally. I get the entire file with www.localhost/file.php, and everything is downloaded. My processor stays on 30% or so. I don't think that I need too much RAM if the algorithm wouldn't not save everything in a big array, but rather create them on the go.

Comment: You said you've looked at the output, and it contains 4.5 million words. The output *should* contain 62 *billion* words. Do you see the problem?

Comment: If there was no problem, this link wouldn't even exist, so that's why I've posted. I am saying that I don't think the hardware might be a problem, but rather the algorithm.

Comment: @user1812076: The algorithm isn't the problem. For Pete's sake, the algorithm even *states* that `k characters from a set of n has n!/(n-k)! possible combinations`. Which part of this is puzzling to you?

Comment: man, come on, really :D I just tried the algorithm posted as a comment, and the file with him algorithm has 300 MB, so ... ?

Comment: ...So you can't calculate? Or read? It is **not possible** to make a complete list of all 8-letter words, unless you write them out directly to a hard drive with >500 GB to spare, because there are **too many of them**.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Still, next time, check the question. It has nothing to do with a hard drive, or RAM or whatever.

Comment: I give up. Of course I've read the question. Have you read my answer? Have you at least tried to understand it? Do you see why `26!/18!` combinations are too much to handle? If you want to find `MBFHPXSN` in your list of words, you have to store that list *somewhere*, right?

Comment: guys I see quite a debate here... I've tried to run the algorithm without printing the combinations just counting them and measuring the time, and run the script more than 2 hours ago and it's still running ...
https://gist.github.com/lackovic10/ac2cb73bdc80ce479dd0

Comment: @lackovic10: Well, let's assume you can generate one million words per second (highly unlikely), then you'll need to wait about a day...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make only 8 letter words, then an iterative solution is possible having 8 nested loops.
Outer most loop index loops from 1 to 26.
Each successive index loops form prev_index+1 to 26.

This way memory will not be over-used.